# Find a nonlinear system conjugate the linear system $\overrightarrow x' = \left(\begin{array}{cc} 1 & 2\\0&-4 \end{array}\right) \overrightarrow x$.

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, dynamical-systems

A nonlinear system that is topologically conjugate in a neighborhood of its equilibrium point to the linear system $\overrightarrow x' = \left(\begin{array}{cc}
1 & 2\\0&-4
\end{array}\right) \overrightarrow x$ near (0,0).

Does this system exist?

Comment: I think you are looking for the Hartman-Grobman theorem. In such case *any* nonlinear vector field with the linear part you wrote answers your question.